# Why I can't move my character with a joystick in Python?

Tags: python, class, pygame, controller

I'm trying to make my game be able to be played with a xbox one controller, I can make it shoot and exit the game but I'm having trouble with the axis (I've tried with the D-pad but it was the same)

**EDIT**: Now i can make it move but It's like a frame, and I need to move the axis multiple times to make it move, I want to hold the axis 1 and that the player moves smoothly and it always moves left for some reason.

This is the `Player` class:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def update(self):
        self.speed_x = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == JOYAXISMOTION:
            if event.axis <= -1 >= -0.2:
                self.speed_x = PLAYER_SPEED
            if event.axis <= 1 >= 0.2:
                self.speed_x = -PLAYER_SPEED
            self.rect.x += self.speed_x
```

Comment: Are you initialising your Joystick(s) ? `joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick( 0 )` and 
    `joystick.init()`.  You should also check `pygame.joystick.get_count()` is non-zero.

Comment: Yes, I've initialised the Joystick, and I tested the Joystick. I can shoot, that means that get_count isn't zero I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing the event data inside `if event.type == JOYAXISMOTION` or `if event.axis`?

Comment: I get numbers like `<Event(1536-JoyAxisMotion {'joy': 0, 'instance_id': 0, 'axis': 1, 'value': -0.05612353892635884})>` (All negatives on the 4 sides and -1 when it's fully pushed)

Comment: old games had function `"calibrate joystick"`. Game asked to move joystick to all directions so it could get max values for all directions and then it could use this to calculate correctly moves.

Comment: if you get max value `x_max = -1` and min value `x_min = -0.05` then center value is `x_center = (x_min + x_max)/2` (more or less `-0.5`) and then if you add it to all values you get max value `-0.5`, min value `+0.5`. Eventually you should move when you get some value - move left when you get value `< -0.6`, and move right when you get `> -0.4`

Answer (score 2):

The Joystick only gives you notice of *changes* to position.  So if it's previously sent an event to say that the joystick's left-right axis is at `0.5`, then joystick axis is *still* at `0.5`.

So you probably need something like:

```
    PLAYER_SPEED = 7

    ...
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == JOYAXISMOTION:
            if event.axis == 1:                              # possibly left-right
                player.speed_x = PLAYER_SPEED * event.value  
            elif event.axis == 2:                            # possibly up-down    
                player.speed_y = PLAYER_SPEED * event.value
     ...


     # In main loop        
     movePlayer( player.speed_x, player.speed_y )
```

How the axes map to up/down and left/right is dependent on the joystick type.  So maybe you will need to reverse the mapping.

Comment: It kinda works (by this I mean that it doesn't crash the game), but I have the same result, the player doesn't move. But thanks.

Comment: @Bluva - I would then add some `print()`s to ensure you're getting the events correctly.